# Emptying memory after calling Geoprocessing service?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcobjects, c#, geoprocessing-service, arcgis-9.2

I'm following this sample for ADF libraries

http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/NET_Server_Doc/developer/samples/Web_Applications/ArcGIS_Buffer_Geoprocessing/ee05ac98-384b-4dbe-b8e3-8d741180dc9a.htm

I'm practically drawing a circle around a point with a geoprocessing service. The radius is about 20 km.

The code is working fine, but the "Clear" routine isn't. Every time I clear the map from the previous data, the memory of the buffer service isn't cleared too and I get this

[image: http://img814.imageshack.us/img814/101/errorrc.jpg]

The code of the "Clear" routine is the same of the sample, but isn't working:

```
// Clears features from all graphics layers in the resource specified by _graphicsResourceName
protected void ClearGraphics()
{
    // Retrieve the resource and clear its graphics dataset
    ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Web.DataSources.Graphics.MapResource graphicsMapResource =
        Map1.GetFunctionality(_graphicsResourceName).Resource as
        ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Web.DataSources.Graphics.MapResource;
    graphicsMapResource.Graphics.Clear();

// This won't work too
GeoprocessingResourceManager1.GetResource(0).ClearState();

// Refresh the resource and copy the map's callback results to the callback results collection so
// the graphics are removed from the map
Map1.RefreshResource(graphicsMapResource.Name);
_callbackResultCollection.CopyFrom(Map1.CallbackResults);
}
```

This should be simple but I can't figure out how to solve this.. the only solution I found is to restart the IIS server which is obviously very bad

Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by clearing the jobs queue

Comment: You should go ahead check your own answer as the solution once the system allows you to, that way others know it is resolved.

Comment: You're totally right!